# Cauchy-Schwarz on a Euclidian Space

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I was thinking about this proof of the cauchy-schwarz inequality,

I wanna show that $$|\langle u,v\rangle|\leq|u||v|$$.

We know that,

$$|\langle u,v\rangle| = ||u||v|\cos{\theta}|$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$.

But $-1 \leq \cos{\theta} \leq 1$, so,
$$0\leq|\langle u,v\rangle|\leq|u||v|$$
where the equality holds if and only if $|\cos{\theta}|=1$, that is, $u$ and $v$ are linearly dependent.

This is correct? For which spaces? Only for $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Thanks :]

Comment: This reasoning is correct in $\mathbb{R}^n$ not necessarily in different Hilbert spaces there the inner product is not defined as you did. So not with an angle and cosine. The inequality holds though.

Comment: So it's correct in every space where the inner product is defined as ⟨u,v⟩=|u||v|cosθ, right?
Thank you :]

Comment: I think that I has to hold in any Hilbert space. Because $u,v$ span two dimensional space. So you can work in this two dimensional space. Thus it is sufficient to prove the inequality in 2d.

Comment: Actually, this is the *definition* of angles of vectors for an inner product space.